# Multiplayer MMO and playback for an audience

Tags: networking, audio, video, gaming, playback

I have an interesting challenge for the Superuser Elite. I'm setting up a 4 user LAN for an MMO in my basement. In addition to this, I'd like to mount a big screen LCD television on my wall for others to watch the action. I haven't purchased anything yet, and my budget is pretty flexible. I know I'll need a really powerful PC to act as the server, 4 PCs and 4 LCD monitors to run the game client (most likely the same model of each), some kind of router or hub to link the PCs to the server, a nice TV to connect the PC displays to, and maybe some nice surround sound to enhance the experience. The following concerns need to be addressed:

1. What kind of equipment will allow me to link the PC displays to the television? (I want a 2x2 grid showing on the tv)
2. Is there a way to isolate the sound and choose the audio of 1 of the 4 systems at any given time? (Not mandatory but would be nice if possible)

This is a special project I'm doing for my daughter, so she can have a little hangout for her and her friends. Any advice or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Commercial MMOs don't sell their server software, so how'd you get it?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the software that you'll need is open source.

You'll need the following:

**Server (Linux):**

1. [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/download.html?) with [RTMP module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Getting-started-with-nginx-rtmp) (Nginx and RTMP module will need to be compiled via source)
2. [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) (Will potentially need to be compiled from source)
3. A website created with 4 embedded players on a page that can stream rtmp. (MediaElement, JW Player, Flow Player, Native HTML5 are a few players which support rtmp) each player within the page will need to be configured to connect to each client datasource streaming rtmp to the nginx server on the local machine.

**Game Clients**

1. [OBS Software](https://obsproject.com/)

There are tutorials online that will help you get there. However, that's beyond the scope of your questions.  Question number 2 can be done pragmatically once you have the streams on the page from #3 above within the server setup.

Hope this helps get you somewhere.

If all else fails there's always [Twitch](http://www.twitch.tv).